# Add Google trust badge to Magento2

Tags: javascript, magento2

I am struggling with google badge. i added: java script to footer Miscellaneous HTML. made the following changes in red.

```js
    <!-- BEGIN: Google Trusted Stores -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var gts = gts || [];

  gts.push(["id", "XXXXXXX"]);
  gts.push(["badge_position", "BOTTOM_RIGHT"]);
  gts.push(["locale", "en_US"]);
  

  (function() {
    var gts = document.createElement("script");
    gts.type = "text/javascript";
    gts.async = true;
    gts.src = "https://www.googlecommerce.com/trustedstores/api/js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gts, s);
  })();
</script>
<!-- END: Google Trusted Stores -->
```

..............................................................

the second part: what is the path to my to my success page in magento 2.1?

google requires some information, wwhat is the best way to obtain this, are these my attribute listed in my magento?

```js
<!-- START Google Trusted Stores Order -->
<div id="gts-order" style="display:none;" translate="no">

  <!-- start order and merchant information -->
  <span id="gts-o-id">MERCHANT_ORDER_ID</span>
  <span id="gts-o-email">CUSTOMER_EMAIL</span>
  <span id="gts-o-country">CUSTOMER_COUNTRY</span>
  <span id="gts-o-currency">CURRENCY</span>
  <span id="gts-o-total">ORDER_TOTAL</span>
  <span id="gts-o-discounts">ORDER_DISCOUNTS</span>
  <span id="gts-o-shipping-total">ORDER_SHIPPING</span>
  <span id="gts-o-tax-total">ORDER_TAX</span>
  <span id="gts-o-est-ship-date">ORDER_EST_SHIP_DATE</span>
  <span id="gts-o-est-delivery-date">ORDER_EST_DELIVERY_DATE</span>
  <span id="gts-o-has-preorder">HAS_BACKORDER_PREORDER</span>
  <span id="gts-o-has-digital">HAS_DIGITAL_GOODS</span>
  <!-- end order and merchant information -->

  <!-- start repeated item specific information -->
  <!-- item example: this area repeated for each item in the order -->
  <span class="gts-item">
    <span class="gts-i-name">ITEM_NAME</span>
    <span class="gts-i-price">ITEM_PRICE</span>
    <span class="gts-i-quantity">ITEM_QUANTITY</span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-id">ITEM_GOOGLE_SHOPPING_ID</span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-store-id">ITEM_GOOGLE_SHOPPING_ACCOUNT_ID</span>
  </span>
  <!-- end item 1 example -->
  <!-- end repeated item specific information -->

</div>
<!-- END Google Trusted Stores Order -->
```

Thank you